# Why should I execute these commands?

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I found these commands in a tutorial to setup selenium on linux. I'm not sure what they do, or why they are needed.

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

The post in question is here:
https://www.ultralinux.org/post/how-to-install-selenium-python-in-linux/

Comment: [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) -- [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

Comment: So is it to prevent users who don't have sudo from using it? And the second part to make it executable. Sorry I'm new to linux

Comment: Execute above commands to configure ChromeDriver on your system. 
Change the path accordingly if your installation directory was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command make the superuser the owner of `chromedriver`. This is a good idea for programs that are installed in `/usr/bin`, to prevent ordinary users from modifying them (I assume the file is only writable by the owner, which is the usual default).

The second command adds execute permission for the user, group and others. This ensures that anyone can run the program.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm new to linux so I wasn't sure if it was malicious.

Comment: Execute below commands to configure ChromeDriver on your system. 
Change the path accordingly if your installation directory was different.

Comment: @ShehanJayalath What are "below commands"?